# Show first 5 elements in a list and then have a link to display the remaining values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with 50 values, and I would like to display only the first 5 values in it and provide a "read more" link. When the user clicks that link, the rest of the values will be displayed.

code:

```
<?php
foreach($abc as $ac) {
    //print_r($ac);
    echo '<li><a class="abc" id="'.$ac->Id.'" href="#">'.$ac->Name.'</a></li>';
}?>

<a href="#" >More<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
```

How can I do it in a loop?

Comment: Why do you have two closing brackets to one foreach? Either way you need a counter or slice the array. And I'm not sure this can be done with only PHP. Probably need js and/or Ajax. And your "array" is actually an object.

Comment: I updated the question, i want to show starting 5 values and  display after clink on more rest of the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display the rest of the values in the same page without reloading the page, navigating to another page or loading asynchronously (e.g. with AJAX) the seemingly only plausible way would be to use JavaScript and CSS.

One way is to add CSS classes to hide the items starting with the 5<sup>th</sup> element and then when the user clicks the *More* link, a class will be added to the list element (e.g. `<ul>`, `<ol>`) such that a CSS rule will reveal the hidden list items.

First, add CSS like this:

```
#linksList li.hidden {
    display: none;
}
#linksList.expanded li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Notice those selectors apply to list items under an element with [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute "linksList". Add an [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) value to the parent element of the list items if there isn't already one (e.g. `<ul id="linksList">`).

Then when iterating over the list items, use the associative style [*foreach*](http://php.net/foreach) (i.e. `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)`). Then check if the index is greater than 4 and if so, add a class name to the list item tag (i.e. `<li>`).

```
<ul id="linksList">
<?php
foreach($abc as $index => $ac){
    $class = '';
    if ($index > 4) {
        $class = 'class="hidden"';
    }
    echo '<li '.$class.'><a class="abc" id="'.$ac->Id.'" href="#">'.$ac->Name.'</a></li>';
}
```

Then we need a way to detect when the user clicks the link labeled *More*. I would suggest adding an [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute:

```
<a id="showMore" href="#" >More<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
```

For the Javascript, we can add event listeners with [document.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to ensure that the DOM is ready before accessing the DOM contents (with the [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event) and then listen for clicks. If the user clicked on the link labeled *showMore* then we add the class *expanded* to the list tag:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
            if (clickEvent.target.id == 'showMore') {
                linksList.classList.add('expanded');
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

For a demonstration of this, see [this PHP playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/XmFL3CjxELPMPfIh).

#### Update:

In order to hide the link labeled '*More*', the CSS rule for class *hidden* can be alterred to be more generic.

This rule:

```
#linksList li.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Can be generalized to:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

That way the display of **any** element with the class name *hidden* will be turned off. Utilizing that, that class name can be added to the link (i.e. the click event target):

```
if (clickEvent.target.id == 'showMore') {
    linksList.classList.add('expanded');
    clickEvent.target.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

The PHP playground appears to be not loading at the moment. See a demonstration in [this PHP fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gsx8-n0z0)

Comment: But how to hide "more" after clicking on more  link @Sam

Comment: Please see my updated answer, including the section at the end under the heading **Update:**

Comment: Thanks  for answer , i aaded document.getElementById("showMore").style.display = 'none'; like this its woking

Comment: Okay - that works but if you do that many times in a page it is better to apply a class instead of modifying the style directly. See [_Stop Writing Slow Javascript_](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/) for the explanation.

Comment: How to add Less(content back to 5 items) after expand

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this :

```
$yourArray = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i");
$first_five_elements = array_slice($yourArray, 0, 5);
$remaining_array_alements = array_slice($yourArray, 5);

print_r($first_five_elements);
print_r($remaining_array_alements);
```

The `array_slice()` function returns selected parts of an array. In this, first parameter is the starting position of the array from where we need to slice the array. It returned back the remaining array from this position to the last if we skip the second parameter which is the length of the elements we need to slice. For more info, visit here https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp

Then iterate the array for your output. After click on More button, you can show the `$remaining_array_alements`

Comment: can you please eloborate the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a short solution that you can adapt it.

```
<?php
        $yourArray = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i");
        $first_five_elements = array_slice($yourArray, 0, 5);
        foreach($first_five_elements as $array_element){
        echo '<li><a class="abc" id="'.$array_element->Id.'" href="#">'.$array_element->Name.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '<a href="#" >More<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' 
        $yourArray = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i");
        $first_rest_elements = array_slice($yourArray, 5, sizeof(yourArray)-5;
        foreach($first_rest_elements as $array_element){
                echo '<li><a class="abc" id="'.$array_element->Id.'" href="#">'.$array_element->Name.'</a></li>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: not second page ,i want to display ot in that page only Mohammad

Comment: its not working, my array values is in loop so its coming as repeated